# ROS_INFO a String

Tags: ros, ros-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi there, this is a question with regards to the "Writing publisher subscriber" tutorial with c++. I've realized that for strings we have to add in .c_str()

What is this .c_str() thing? We add it in when

> ROS_INFO("%s", msg.data.c_str());

why cant we just.

> ROS_INFO("%s", msg.data);

And i've also realized this is specific only for strings. Thanks in advanced to whoever helped me out :)

edit:
I did my own personal reading and found a few resources pretty helpful in understanding this. check out https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/07/26/stdstring-vs-c-strings/

Enjoy :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403926/ros_info-a-string/) by [sajid1122](https://answers.ros.org/users/103351/sajid1122/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2022-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By [the C++ documentation](https://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/):

```
const char* c_str() const noexcept;
```

> #### Get C string equivalent
>
> Returns a pointer to an array that contains a
> null-terminated sequence of characters
> (i.e., a C-string) representing the
> current value of the string object.
>
> This array includes the same sequence
> of characters that make up the value
> of the string object plus an
> additional terminating null-character
> ('\0') at the end.
>
> #### Return Value
>
> A pointer to the c-string representation of the string
> object's value.

`c_str` returns a `const char*` that points to a null-terminated string (i.e. a C-style string).

It is useful when you want to pass the "contents" of a `std::string` to a function that expects to work with a C-style string.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sajid1122](https://answers.ros.org/users/103351/sajid1122/) on 2022-07-19**:
Hi, thanks for your. Answer, very helpful. But i have a followup question.

Why do we have to pass the string pointer and not the string as a whole. coz like you mentioned, the return value is a pointer to the c-string. Why do we need to return a pointer? why cant we just return the actual string itself.

Anyways, your answer was very helpful. Do answer my follow-up question when you get the chance if not its alright too :)

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-07-19**:
I based my answer on similar questions in the past, e.g. https://answers.ros.org/question/49042/cannot-ouput-string-service-via-ros_info/

> A string type in a ROS
> message/service maps to a `std::string`
> in C++ (see the [msg package](https://wiki.ros.org/msg) for more
> details). `std::string`'s are not
> printable with something like `printf`,
> unless you get access to the
> underlying `const char*` data which is
> what `printf`'s `"%s"` format string is
> expecting. You can get access to the
> C-string via the `c_str()` member on
> `std::string`.

**Comment by [sajid1122](https://answers.ros.org/users/103351/sajid1122/) on 2022-07-19**:
Yup, thanks for sharing that link. I think that answers my question. Thanks a lot mate.